# How to have a queue of methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Suppose I want to call some methods of a car, for example `drive(30, 5)`, `rotate(45)`, `stop()`.

How can I have a queue of methods, for example `[drive(30,5), rotate(45), stop()]` so that I can execute the first function, wait until it ends and call the next?

All these methods are Coroutines (`IEnumerators`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ms = new List<Action>()
{
    () => drive(30, 5),
    () => rotate(45),
    () => stop()
};


for (int i = 0; i < ms.Count; i++)
{
    ms[i](); // Invoke
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using C# Actions and Co-routines you can!
The following is all Pseudo-Code but can be elaborated on !
Imagine!

```
Using System;
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    myDefaultWaitTime = SomeFloat;
    myQueue = new List<Action>();



    void AddAction(Action myNewAction)
    {
        myQueue.Add(myNewAction);
    }
    Action myNextAction()
    {
        Action myAction = myQueue[0];
        myQueue.delete(0);
        return myAction;
    }

    IEnumerator WaitToLoad(Action myAction)
        {
            float currentWaitTime = 0;
            while (currentWaitTime < defaultWaitTime)
            {
                currentWaitTime += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
            StartCoroutine(myNextAction());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerator Drive(int x, int y)
{
    // driving routine here.
}

public IEnumerator Rotate(float angle)
{
    // rotation routine here.
}

public IEnumerator Stop()
{
   // Stop routine here
}

public IEnumerator ExecuteAll()
{
    // Drive
    yield return new StartCoroutine(Drive(30,5));

    // rotate
    yield return new StartCoroutine(Rotate(45));

    // Stop
    yield return new StartCoroutine(Stop());


    // All actions are done.
}


public void StartAll()
{
   StartCoroutine(ExecuteAll());
}
```

Comment: I need a queue, I used these functions as an exemple but it can be a lot more, which I would need to add at runtime.